# IE 6 CSS issue with margin and padding

Tags: internet-explorer

My CSS works perfectly well in FF, IE7 and IE8. If I open the page in IE6, the margin and padding is not working, but when I reload or refresh the page, the problem is automatically solved in this situation. What is my fault?

Comment: With IE6 this is only the tip of the iceberg. You will find more *funny* stuff later...  P.S. Maybe you could post some code?

Answer (score 0):

Internet explorer has lots of CSS bugs. IE6 is and old navigator with very very poor CSS support. 
Some important sites are in the way to remove the support to this browser to move the users to use newer browsers with new features.

Also IE6 Is very very insecure navigator *"IF you use IE6 you are calling the malware to your PC"*

About the CSS heres a list of bugs: http://haslayout.net/css/index

and other: http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html

I can't make more without some code.